# Finding the operator norm in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing, operator-theory, normed-spaces, functional-inequalities

There is an operator given:
$K: X \to Y$,
$(Kf)(x) = \int \limits_0^1 k(x, y)f(y) \mbox{d}y$.
Let's define: $X = L^P([0, 1]), Y = L^q([0, 1])$, where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1, k \in L^q([0, 1]^2)$.
The task is to prove whether the operator $K$ is bounded and then to calculate it's norm.

---

**My attempt**
$$||Kf||_q^q = \int \limits_{0}^{1} \bigg( \bigg|\int \limits_0^1 k(x,y)f(y) \mbox{d}y \bigg| \bigg)^q \mbox{d}x \le \int \limits_{0}^{1} \bigg( \int \limits_0^1 |k(x,y)f(y)| \mbox{d}y  \bigg)^q \mbox{d}x.$$
Now I would say that a "trick" with adding the $p$-th power and afterwards the usage of [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality). I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: Try searching for "integral kernel", "integral operator", "schur's criterion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the operator is bounded you can use Hölder's inequality and get 
$\int_0^1 \left( \vert k(x,y) \vert \vert f(y)\vert dy \right)^q dx \leq
\int_0^1 \left( \left( \int_0^1 \vert k(x,y) \vert^q dy \right)^{\frac{1}{q}} \Vert f \Vert_p  \right)^q dx = \Vert f \Vert_p^q
\int_0^1 \left( \left( \int_0^1 \vert k(x,y) \vert^q dy \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}  \right)^q dx $.
The latter integral exists as $k \in L^q([0,1]^2)$.
This shows that $K$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you! It's a clear and nice solution.